# Generating UUIDs with Swift

Tags: swift, uuid

I'm trying to generate a UUID using Swift. The official documentation is confusing me a little bit.

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/uuid) says

> `init?(uuidString: String)`
>   Create a UUID from a string such as “E621E1F8-C36C-495A-93FC-0C247A3E6E5F”.

Does this mean that the string I need to create the UUID from has to be in that format?

For a project I'm doing, I have a string and I want to generate a UUID specifically for that string.

Here's what I tried:

```
import Foundation

var str = UUID(uuidString: "Hello World")
print(str.uuidString)
```

This gives me the error,

> value of optional type 'UUID?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!'
>   or '?'?

I'm still very new to Swift and all this. I don't know what to do in this case.

Basically, I need to generate a UUID SPECIFICALLY for a string (such as "Hello world"), and then I want to use the UUID to return the original string.

Comment: Generating a UUID from a string makes no sense. That’s not what a UUID is. You need to explain your goal.

Comment: It sounds like you are talking about needing a two way hash.

Answer (score 10):

`UUID().uuidString` is used to generate UUIDs. You need to `import Foundation` to use it.

This is a UUID: `E621E1F8-C36C-495A-93FC-0C247A3E6E5F`

They are generated from "nothing", they are unique. If you wanted to generate an ID given some string, and generate that same ID at any time using that string, then an UUID will not work for you.

Is it possible you are looking for Base64 encoding?

With Base64, for example, you can encode `Hello World` as `SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ=`, and then decode `SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ=` as `Hello World`.

Answer (score 6):

**Short answer to your questions**:

1) Yes, you must provide a string in the proper format for a UUID, similar to the example:

```
UUID(uuidString: "E621E1F8-C36C-495A-93FC-0C247A3E6E5F")
```

The code you're using, `UUID(uuidString: "Hello World")`, will return `nil`.

2) It looks like what you really want to do is encrypt and decrypt the string. There's a lot of information on that, and many ways to do it. You might want to start with the [Certificate, Key, and Trust Services Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001358-CH218-SW1).

*Update: for anyone coming here because they need to generate an actual UUID -*
At the Terminal command line, enter `uuidgen`.

*Further update:* to generate a UUID programmatically in Swift (as of 3.1), do this:

```
import Foundation

let myUUID: String = UUID().uuidString
```

**Explanation for the error message**:

Note the question mark in the documented statement:

```
init?(uuidString: String)
```

In Swift, any type followed by a `?` is an **optional type**, meaning the result will contain either a value of the specified type (`UUID` here) or nothing (`nil`).

Clicking the link for the `init?` statement in the documentation, you'll notice the [Discussion section](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/uuid/1779760-init) does indeed indicate:

> Returns nil for invalid strings.

You're getting the error because **Swift must be told what to do with those possible `nil` results**.

You must either:

- code specific handling for the possible `nil` result. (Swift provides the `if
  let` and `guard` statements for this, for example.) **OR**
- "**force unwrap**" the optional type. In this case you tell Swift that you're SURE the results WON'T be `nil` by adding an `!` following the possible `nil` item.

In your case, "force unwrapping the optional" would look like:

```
print(str.uuidString!)
```

Of course, even though this compiles without the error message, it would crash when the invalid string ("Hello World") came along, producing a `nil`. (Swift doesn't like when you lie about possible `nil` values, lol!) So, be careful to ***force unwrap only values you're certain won't be `nil`***!

Comment: I would say it is probably better to not mention ! as your default solution even though you mention it is not the way to go. An example with guard implemented would've provided more value to someone learning and getting used to the swift way of things.

Comment: Since the OP's particular error message, @AntwanvanHoudt, mentions the term *unwrapped*, I wanted to explain force unwrapping. I mentioned `if let` and `guard` so the reader can look those up to learn about them on their own. And, I certainly made it clear that one should NOT force unwrap unless they're SURE a value won't be `nil`.